# A term to describe the sum of column space and null space of a matrix

Tags: matrices

I would like to know if there is a term that describes the sum of column space and null space of a matrix ? Is dimension of matrix a correct description ?

Thanks

Comment: I presume of a square matrix, right?

Comment: Yeah I am trying to describe a square matrix